# React Native expo. Creating variable earlier and using it later

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating mobile app using react native expo. I want to create a variable beforehand and then later use it. see commented code below. I have added comments at critical lines below:-

```
export default function bar () {

        let result;            // create variable early

        // ...

        const pick = async () => {
        
                result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({   // use variable later
                mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
                allowsEditing: true,
                quality: 1,
            });
        }

        pick();


    return (
    <Image source={{ uri: result.uri }} />    // Use later
    );

}
```

But my App crashes at `pick();` It starts building again. Why is my app crashing at `pick();` ? I believe I have done something wrong with `result` variable?

**NOTE**: I dont want to use hooks. I want to do without using hooks like `useEffect` or `useState`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export default function bar() {
  let result; // create variable early

  // ...

  const pick = async () => {
    result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      // use variable later
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    });
  };

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    pick();
  });

  return result ? <Image source={{ uri: result.uri }} /> : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to use hooks like `useEffect`. It gives me error. I want to do without hooks

Comment: @NightCoder101 You can handle the error as I have updated my answer check

Comment: Thanks You for your efforts. But You are using `useEffect` in your answer. I want to avoid `useEffect` and any other hook

Comment: @NightCoder101 I think to use `useEffect` is better approach in this way

Answer (score 0):

1. First Initialize a state,
2. Create a button by pressing your pick function will call.
3. In pick func take a result from Imagepicker and set that back to your result state by calling setResult(result)
4. Now the image will automatically rerender when your setResult func call.

**Complete Code**

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { View, Button } from "react-native";
    
    const bar = () => {
      const [result, setResult] = useState(""); // Initializing the state
    
      const pick = async () => {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          // use variable later
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          quality: 1,
        });
        setResult(result); // Setting the image uri in the state
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: result.uri }} />
          <Button title="Select Image" onPress={pick} /> // pass your pick func to
          button press
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default bar;
```